# how can i get the indexpath.section for JT Apple calendar view

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, jtapplecalendar

I'm using the JT Apple calendar pod to display the calendar 
what i would like to do is to put two buttons ( previous and next to scroll fast than swiping left or right )
but i can't find a way to get the index path for the collection view

[image]

```
> func configureCalendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView) ->
> ConfigurationParameters
>     {
>         formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"
>         formatter.timeZone = Calendar.current.timeZone
>         formatter.locale = Calendar.current.locale
>         let startDate = Date() //today
>        let endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value:2, to: startDate)   let parameters = ConfigurationParameters(startDate:
> startDate, endDate: endDate!)
>         return parameters
>     }
```

I need to implement the nextButtonPressed to swipe right and the Previous Button but without passing the corresponding dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to find the index path for the collectionView.

just call these functions,

```
calendarView.scrollToSegment(.next)      // Scrolls to next
calendarView.scrollToSegment(.previous)  // Scrolls to previous
calendarView.scrollToSegment(.start)     // Scrolls to start of calendar
calendarView.scrollToSegment(.end)       // Scrolls to end of calendar
```

Comment: Hello 
the date starts from today and ends 2 months later 
for example  September is the current date 
 October and  November are the 2 months after September.
I don't want to reach  December while pressing the Next button
or August while pressing the  Previous button

Comment: I do not understand. Can you create an issue on github? I will respond there. And please be very detailed about the issue to help me understand.